Delete entire row if duplicate is found in a specific column
I want to delete the entire row if a duplicate is found in column AF is found.  There are a few different numbers in the column and I am trying to only keep one row associated with each number in that column.  I keep getting an error that says, "Unable to get Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
    matchFoundIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 2),Range("AF1:AF" & lastRow), 0)
    If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
       Cells(iCntr, 1).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
End If
Next


Cells(iCntr, 2) refers to a cell in column B. Are you intending to check if its value exists in column AF?
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

yes column AF, so I should use 32 instead of 2?

So I used column 32 and it seems to work but only one at a time.  It won't do the whole column.  I am missing something to make it continue until there are only different values left in the column and all other rows deleted.  Having a code brain freeze

Never remove entries from beginning to end: if you need to remove two subsequent ones, the second one will not be deleted. Always remove entries, starting at the end, and then going back to the beginning.

Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDups()

    Const COL = "AF"
    Dim r As Long, lastRow As Long, dict, k, n As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = lastRow To 1 Step -1
            k = Trim(.Cells(r, COL))
            If Len(k) > 0 Then
               If dict.exists(k) Then
                    .Rows(r).Delete
                    n = n + 1
               Else
                    dict.Add k, r
               End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox lastRow & " rows scanned " & n & " rows deleted", vbInformation

End Sub


Absolutely perfect, thank you so much.

Loading data into an array is a more efficient approach when working with large datasets. Additionally, using a Dictionary object to identify duplicate values in column AF is a good option.
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim r As Long, sKey As String, rngDel As Range
    Const TARGET_COL = "AF"
    Dim iCol As Long: iCol = Cells(1, TARGET_COL).Column  ' get the column id
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim arr: arr = Range("A1:AF" & lastRow).Value ' load data into an array
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' loop through rows
    For r = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        sKey = arr(r, iCol) ' Col AF '
        If dict.exists(sKey) Then ' found duplicated value
            Set rngDel = MergeRng(rngDel, Cells(r, 1))
        Else
            dict(sKey) = ""
        End If
    Next
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then ' remove rows
        rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub

' Merge two range
Function MergeRng(ByRef RngAll As Range, ByRef RngSub As Range) As Range
    If RngAll Is Nothing Then
        Set RngAll = RngSub
    ElseIf Not RngSub Is Nothing Then
        Set RngAll = Application.Union(RngAll, RngSub)
    End If
    Set MergeRng = RngAll
End Function



